# Facebook Feed Dialog through WebView in Unity is Blank

Tags: facebook, webview, dialog, feed

I have been using a WebView dropped into Unity(Found here: https://github.com/gree/unity-webview) for implementing Facebook connection. The WebView has been working very well for authorization of the user in the OAuth dialog, but when I try to access the feed dialog for posting to a friend, I end up with a blank white screen. The same generated URL when dropped into a browser works just fine.

The feed dialog URL I generate looks like this:
http://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?access_token={Access Token}&app_id={App ID}&from={Authroized User}&to={Selected Friend ID}&link={Post Link}&name={Post Name}&
description={Post Description}&redirect_uri={My Redirect Page.aspx}

Example of the functioning Auth dialog URL I generate looks like this:
http://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={App ID}&redirect_uri={My Auth Redirect.aspx}&scope=publish_stream,publish_actions&response_type=token

Wondering if anyone knows what could be causing this with this particular WebView.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was tearing my hair out about this but got to the bottom of it. I had tried escaping the URL and it did not work the other day - but then I tried escaping just the values of some of the parameters being sent that had spaces this morning. This seemed to fix it. Simple mistake, but if anyone runs into this, don't forget ESCAPING IS EVERYTHING! Often you are working in something higher level(At least I am) where URLs and parameters get escaped automatically, lesson learned I guess :D